# What's the best way to have a Mule ESB flow monitor a Hazelcast Distributed Queue?

Tags: mule, esb, hazelcast

I have a cluster of Mule ESB containers, each of which is running an (identical) application which share responsibility for handling work which arrives as objects in a Hazelcast Distributed Queue.

Question: What's the best way to have these applications monitor the queue?

Conceptually, I imagine a "Hazelcast Queue Endpoint" that sits blocked on the queue until an object shows up-- but I'm not quite sure how to realize this.

(Mule ESB 3.3, community edition).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [DevKit](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Anypoint+Connector+DevKit+Guide) to create a custom a Hazelcast Queue Endpoint and build it as a custom module.

This custom module would be usable in Studio and raw Mule.